# search solana address which meets conditions

Tags: solana

Is it possible to search solana address which meets all the following conditions?

- address starts with specific letters
- address ends with specific letters
- specific token balance is specific number at a specific point in the past

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of these are possible with the normal JSON RPC calls provided by a Solana node, but you have two options that you can develop.

- Create an accounts plugin that tracks what you need: addresses with certain start / end letters, and token balances.  More information about how to develop an accounts plugin at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-accountsdb-plugin-postgres
- Add options to `solana-ledger-tool` to get accounts based on address start and end.  Currently it just prints out all the accounts by running `solana-ledger-tool accounts -l my-ledger`, but you could put in a PR to add some filters for the start and end letters in base-58 encoding.  The source code for it can be found at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/tree/master/ledger-tool.  Note that this requires a validator ledger, which would require you to run your own node.